# Page Personalization Image with Deep link in Oracle Fusion HCM employment info page

Tags: oracle-soa, oracle-fusion-apps

I have a requirement to add a small image and image has embedded with a Deep link. This is I want to add on the Oracle Fusion HCM > 'Employment Info' page.

Did anyone worked on this requirement using page personalization or any other method in SaaS module.
Deep link: https:///fscmUI/faces/deeplink?objType=DIRECTORY_ORG_CHART&action=NONE

I did not find any document or process to achieve both image with deep link.